# Select rows which are there in one table and not there in another table by matching two columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-null

I have two tables as shown below

t1:

```
cust_id   product       score
1         bat           0.8
2         ball          0.3
2         phone         0.6
3         tv            1.0
2         bat           1.0
4         phone         0.2
1         ball          0.6
```

t2:

```
cust_id          product
1                bat
2                phone
3                tv
```

From the above table I would like to filter rows which are there in `t1` and not in `t2` by matching the columns `cust_id` and `product`

Expected output:

```
cust_id   product       score
2         ball          0.3
2         bat           1.0
4         phone         0.2
1         ball          0.6
```

I tried below query but it does not works.

```
   SELECT t1.* 
     FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.cust_id = t1.cust_id
     WHERE t2.product IS NUL
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please don't tag conflicting technologies it makes it *harder* to help you. [Edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...by matching two columns values

means that you should use both columns in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
ON t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id AND t2.product = t1.product
WHERE t2.cust_id IS NULL;
```

In the condition in the `WHERE` clause you may use any of the 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only require columns from `t1` here you should use `not exists` which allows the optimiser to avoid fully joining the tables before filtering, you specifiy the columns that should be correlated as part of the *exists* criteria:

```
select cust_id, product, score
from t1
where not exists (
  select * from t2
  where t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id and t2.product = t1.product
);
```